# Proposal: add micro-button to reset tag selection

Tags: feature-request, usability, tags

Unless I missed something, it looks that when I am in the main "Question" tab (the one next to the logo, on the same line with Tags, Users, Badges and Unanswered) and I have selected a tag to filter the available questions for, the only way to reset my tag selection is to click again on the "Question" tab.

I would therefore propose to add the standard little cross next to the selected tags (the one that normally remove the tag from your "interesting tag" or "ignored tags" list) in order to indicate "stop filtering for this tag".

This would also be handy for those cases in which you are filtering questions for several tags and you would like to eliminate just one of the filters (e.g.: you are filtering for "ubuntu", "gnome" and "linux" and would like to filter only for "gnome" and "linux" instead).

Comment: +1 sounds useful to me